# Websockets server with SockJS (NodeJS) + STOMP Clients

Tags: node.js, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I have a node app with sockjs sockets.

Some HTML / JS clients use stomp over sock JS but I don't understand how subscription works :

```
$scope.initSockets = function() {
    $scope.socket.client = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/websockets'); => WORKS

    $scope.socket.stomp = Stomp.over($scope.socket.client);
    $scope.socket.stomp.connect({}, function() {
        $scope.socket.stomp.subscribe("/topic", $scope.notify); => NOTIFY Is never called
    });
    $scope.socket.client.onclose = $scope.reconnect;
};
```

Clients are connected, events are logged but $scope.notify is never called. How can we configure topic subscription ?

Edit :

Note sure I'm clear.

I'm using sockjs module as a websocket server.

There's not a lot of configuration :

`echo.installHandlers(server, {prefix:'/websockets'});`

```
 // on new connection event
echo.on('connection', function(conn) {

    console.log('New client connected : ' + conn.id);

    // add this client to clients object
    clients[conn.id] = conn;

    // on connection close event
    conn.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Client disconnected ' + conn.id);
        delete clients[conn.id];
    });
});
```

Clients use stomp protocol over sockJS client.

They receive messages (regards to client logs), but their are not related to "topic" and are not parsed.

I don't understand how subscription works and how to configure it with sockjs on server side.

Answer (score 1):

Subscription works based on the destination. Default pattern is `/exchange/routingkey`

In your case it is `/topic/notify` which means your subscribe to default exchange `topic` routingkey will be `notify`